# Allow users to approve another task

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions

I have created a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer where I want users to have the ability to approve anothers task if need be. I use a "Custom Task Process" to assign the task to the user.

When a user with higher permission levels, in this case "Full Control" permissions, trys to approve the task for the individual they are prompted with a SharePoint error message that they cannot approve tasks which are assigned to another individual.

What preplexes me is I have a similiar workflow, in which I use the "Custom Task Process" and users with Approver or Full Control permissions can approve another individuals tasks.

Comment: How are the item level permissions set on both lists in the list's Advanced Settings?

Comment: The same, we met with our outside consulting firm, and they believe it had to do with the Site being a subsite and not at the root level of the site collection.

Answer (score 2):

In designer when you edit the workflow under "Task Information" you will see Owner:.  In the owner field I would recommend you place a SharePoint group.  I usually place a group here composed of people that I want to be able to close tasks for others but not have administrative permissions for the site.

After you have inputted a group further down the page you will see "Settings"
Check "Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks".  After that save and publish the workflow.

Hope this Helps.